Document.evalute not resolving XPath
I am tring to use Document.evaluate to extract XPath values from an XML document. However for some reason the return value is always blank. The XML document uses namespaces, so I am passing a namespace resolver:
const manifest = `<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp"> <Id>123</Id> <Version>1.0.0.3</Version> <ProviderName>ACME</ProviderName> </OfficeApp>`;
const domParser = new DOMParser();
const manifestDocument = domParser.parseFromString(manifest, `text/xml`);
const elements = ["ProviderName", "Version", "Id"];

let nsResolver = function nsResolver(prefix) {
  switch (prefix) {
    case "xsi":
      return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    case "bt":
      return "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0";
    case "ov":
      return "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides";
    default:
      return "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1";
  }
};

elements.forEach((element) => {
  const next = manifestDocument.evaluate(
    `//OfficeApp/${element}/text()`,
    manifestDocument,
    nsResolver,
    XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
    null
  );
  console.log(`${element} = ${next.stringValue}`);
});

Thanks and regards,
Andrew

XPath expressions do not consider the default namespace. Use a prefix for it, as in //def:OfficeApp/def:${element}/text().

Also note that later versions of XPath (the current version is 3.1) allow you to declare a default element namespace so with an XPath 3.1 processor like SaxonJS you could use the empty prefix bound to your default namespace URI as follows:


const manifest = `<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp"> <Id>123</Id> <Version>1.0.0.3</Version> <ProviderName>ACME</ProviderName> </OfficeApp>`;
const domParser = new DOMParser();
const manifestDocument = domParser.parseFromString(manifest, `application/xml`);
const elements = ["ProviderName", "Version", "Id"];

elements.forEach((element) => {
  const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(
    `//OfficeApp/${element}/string()`,
    manifestDocument,
    { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'
    }    
  );
  console.log(`${element} = ${result}`);
});
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/SaxonJS-2.6/SaxonJS2.js"></script>



